# ¿Como detectar cuando se suelta el click, de un OnLongClickListener?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Descripción:**

Quiero que al hacer longClick en una ImageView, aparezca un dialog (popup) el cual desaparecería al soltar la pantalla (soltar el click).

**Intenté de esta forma con OnTouch pero no me resultó útil:**

```
holder.img_animales.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //dialog.show();
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                //dialog.dismiss();
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Alguna sugerencia?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega una bandera al método `onTouch()`, cuando se presione la pantalla se devuelve `true`, indicando que la acción de touch no ha terminado, cuando se suelta se devuelve `false` indicando que ya terminó.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      boolean  presionado = false;
      if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            presionado = true;
            //dialog.show();
       }
       else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            presionado = false;
            //dialog.dismiss();
       }


       return presionado;
  }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @Lobos. Tu código funciona pero no se por que no se hace el dismiss del dialog al mover el dedo. De todos modos, tu respuesta no es la que espero ya que quiero hacerlo con un OnLongClick Listener, y que se detecte cuando se suelta el longclick